# Enable HTTPS using incoming port as RewriteCond

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, https

Im trying to resend a request using HTTPS when a particular URL is hit. This is my rule, however it does not cause the request to be resent. Any ideas what is wrong with it?

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 15000

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/securePage$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,R=301,L]

The securePage value is a vanity URL which is supposed to get rewritten when the request is sent for the second time using the new protocol

Thanks,

Comment: The issue was with the port number i was listening on. While my apache server was listening on this port for SSL requests it seems that the rewrite engine still sees it as port 80

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the port i was listening on fixed the issue

## RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80